# Storetext from a table choice correct lines to store for Selenium Ide Ui Vision Kantu

Tags: extract, store, selenium-ide, kantu

I need to storetext all lines from a table where CODICE CATASTALE have a value

I add an image to show, I need to save all line in variable with storetext with this characteristic CODICE CATASTALE have a value, in the image I add 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 to explain line to store.

This is a relative storetext when CODICE CATASTALE have a value stored the line.

Here the page

nonsolocap.it/cap?k=56040

Image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After the execution such script in Selenium IDE `table` variable will contain data from the table. `xpath_to_all_rows_with_CODICE_CATASTALE` should be replaced with corresponding xpath.

```
store xpath count | xpath = xpath_to_all_rows_with_CODICE_CATASTALE | n
store | 0 | j
while | ${j} < ${n} |
store | | rowElement
store | 0 | i
while | ${i} < 7 |
store text | xpath = xpath_to_all_rows_with_CODICE_CATASTALE[${j}]/td[${i}] | element
execute script | if (${i} != 0) var arr = ${rowElement}; else var arr = []; var element = ${element}; arr.push(element); return arr; | rowElement
execute script | return Number(${i}) + 1; | i
end| |
execute script | if (${j} != 0) var arr = ${table}; else var arr = []; var rowElement = ${rowElement}; arr.push(rowElement); return arr; | table
execute script | return Number(${j}) + 1; | j
end| |
```

Answer (score 0):

use scvSave command and give a name for the target for divide raws